# How can I get symlinks and which files they target without any permission info, date, etc.?

Tags: linux, bash, symlink

I want to display info about symlinks and their target files without unnecessary (for this task) information.
So far the best I found is to use this variation of `find`:

```
find -L /path/to/dir/ -xtype l -exec ls -al {} \;
```

This will output something like this:

```
lrwxr--r-- 1 user user 34 Feb 19 09:49 ./testdir1/slink1 -> /test/file.txt
lrwxr--r-- 1 user user 45 Feb 19 10:02 ./testdir1/slink2 -> /test/test2/file2.txt
```

Is there any possible way to get rid of permissions info, date of modification, etc., like below:

`./testdir1/slink2 -> /test/test2/file2.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way, just using pure find solution.

```
find /path/to/file -type l -printf '%-40p  --> %l\n
```

Just remove the `-40` or adjust to desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `readlink` command.

e.g. (adapting your find command):

```
find -L /path/to/dir/ -xtype l -exec readlink {} \;
```

or, to get it as  `source -> target`

```
find -L . -xtype l -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} bash -c 'echo {} "->" "$(readlink {} )"'
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but `readlink` gives only paths to target files